# Possible to have "polymorphic has_one" relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Category
--------
- id
- name

Tag
--------
- id
- tag


Campaign
--------
- id
- name
- target (either a tag *or* a category)
```

Is a polymorphic association the answer here? I can't seem to figure out how to use it with has_one :target, :as => :targetable.

Basically, I want Campaign.target to be set to a Tag or a Category (or potentially another model in the future).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375083/ror-has-one-or-the-other-or-polymorphism-without-the-inheritance

Comment: Slightly different, but yes similar.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I don't believe you're in need of a `has_one` association here, the `belongs_to` should be what you're looking for.

In this case, you'd want a `target_id` and `target_type` column on your Campaign table, you can create these in a rake with a `t.references :target` call (where `t` is the `table` variable).

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now campaign can be associated to either a `Tag` or `Category` and `@campaign.target` would return the appropriate one.

The `has_one` association would be used if you have a foreign key on the target table pointing back to your `Campaign`.

For example, your tables would have

`Tag: id, tag, campaign_id`
`Category: id, category, campaign_id`

and would have a `belongs_to :campaign` association on both of them.  In this case, you'd have to use `has_one :tag` and `has_one :category`, but you couldn't use a generic `target` at this point.

Does that make more sense?

**EDIT**

Since `target_id` and `target_type` are effectively foreign keys to another table, your `Campaign` belongs to one of them.  I can see your confusion with the wording because logically the `Campaign` is the container.  I guess you can think of it as `Campaign` has a single target, and that's a `Tag` or a `Container`, therefore it belongs in a `Tag` or `Container`.

The `has_one` is the way of saying the relationship is defined on the target class.  For example, a `Tag` would have be associated to the campaign through a `has_one` relationship since there's nothing on the tag class that identifies the association.  In this case, you'd have

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :campaign, :as => :target
end
```

and likewise for a `Category`.  Here, the `:as` keyword is telling rails which association relates back to this `Tag`.  Rails doesn't know how to figure this out upfront because there's no association with the name `tag` on the `Campaign`.

The other two options that may provide further confusion are the `source` and `source_type` options.  These are only used in `:through` relationships, where you're actually joining the association `through` another table.  The docs probably describe it better, but the `source` defines the association name, and `source_type` is used where that association is polymorphic. They only need to be used when the target association (on the `:through` class) has a name that isn't obvious -- like the case above with `target and`Tag -- and we need to tell rails which one to use.

Comment: Wow, that totally worked. I guess I had my associations all backwards. I still don't quite understand _why_ it works, but it does. I feel like a Campaign "has_one" target, not "belongs_to" one target. Know what I mean? Can you explain that a little? I get what you're saying about the reverse relationship (using campaign_id) not being necessary though.

Comment: I added a few notes to try and help describe it the way i see it, hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Incredibly helpful. Wish I could award you more points. Thanks!

Comment: how would you modify it if you wanted to have a different association name, say "best_campaign", instead?

Answer (score 7):

The answers to this questions are great, but I just wanted to mention another way to accomplish the same. What you could do instead is create two relationships, eg.:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :category
  validate :tag_and_category_mutually_exclusive

  def target=(tag_or_category)
    case
    when tag_or_category.kind_of?(Tag)
      self.tag = tag_or_category
      self.category = nil
    when tag_or_category.kind_of?(Category)
      self.category = tag_or_category
      self.tag = nil
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Expected Tag or Category"
    end
  end

  def target(tag_or_category)
    tag || category
  end

  private 
  def tag_and_category_mutually_exclusive
    if tag && category
      errors.add "Can't have both a tag and a category"
    end
  end
end
```

The validation ensures that you don't accidentally end up with both fields set, and the `target` helpers allows polymorphic access to the tag/category.

The benefit of doing it like this is that you get a somewhat more correct database schema, where you can define proper foreign key constraints on the id columns. This will also lead to nicer and more efficient sql queries on the database level.

Comment: Thank you @troelskn for such a super piece of code, what a great way to help ensure database consistency in this messy Rails world.

Answer (score 1):

Slight addendum: In the migration where you created the `Campaign` table, the `t.references :target` call should have `:polymorphic => true` (at least with rails 4.2)

Comment: `polymorphic: true` :D